# Download large file from url to server without blocking php application

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a laravel application where I want to download a large file from URL to my application server with downloading progress status. Its working but it blocks the whole app and no other user able to access any page of my application.

```
$fileHandler = fopen('data.zip', 'w');
$fileUrl = "http://212.183.159.230/5MB.zip";
$client = new Client();
$promise = $client->request('GET', $fileUrl,  [
            'sink' => $fileHandler,
            'progress' => function ($dl_total_size, $dl_size_so_far, $ul_total_size, $ul_size_so_far) {
                $percentageDownloaded = ($dl_total_size > 0) ? (($dl_size_so_far / $dl_total_size) * 100) : 0;
                File::put('/download-percentage.txt', $percentageDownloaded);
            },
            'verify' => false
        ]);
```

Library I am using
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: One user's activity shouldn't be blocking all other users' ability to interact with any other page. You're more likely just blocking yourself using the same PHP session. You might try testing using two different browsers to verify if they really are blocking each other. Or if you're only blocking your own additional requests using the same cookie and thus same session until your session is unlocked. Try testing on chrome vs firefox (or something like that) to see if the two browsers block one another.

Comment: you may use laravel Queues https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#synchronous-dispatching and a package like https://github.com/imTigger/laravel-job-status to monitor it's status.

Comment: The other possibly is if you're testing this through artisan serve. You'd get a different result going through Apache or similar which would have more threads available to serve more incoming requests.

Comment: @Kevin Y Thanks